# Invoking iOS application when an ibeacon is in range

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, ibeacon

I have an iOS application (on iphone) that is triggered when an ibeacon (server) is in range. It runs fine as long as the application is running either in the background or foreground.

Is there a way of invoking the app when it's not running and detects an ibeacon?

What I understood by reading the CLLocationManager Class Reference by Apple is that this kind of functionality is possible but I may be wrong.

However, if anyone is aware of how this can be achieved, a brief example is appreciated.

There were similar questions posted but seemed pretty vague so decided to ask again

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been asking this question for weeks now and the answer is no.

Apple was quite clear in the developer forums about this:

"Note, what I'm talking about is if the user explicitly kills the app in the app switcher.  At that point the user has told us that this app should not be running, and we will honor that by not re-launching the app any more.  If the app is terminated by the OS (e.g. due to memory pressure) then we will continue to launch the app for region monitoring.  Hopefully that clarifies a bit.

And if the app is simply suspended (i.e. the user hits the home button to leave the app) then yes, we will continue resuming the app when regions are entered/exited.  The only change in iOS 7 is if the user explicitly kills the app in the app switcher."

https://devforums.apple.com/message/886796#886796

Comment: As of iOS7.1, apps will still launch on an iBeacon event even if the app is killed by the user.

Answer (score 1):

I see there is an accepted answer for this question, but it is not strictly correct.  You absolutely *can* make an app launch based on an iBeacon coming into range.

A detailed proof is in my blog post here: http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2013/11/13/ibeacon-monitoring-in-the-background-and-foreground.html

Comment: Hey David - you're right of course, your app can range if the app is in the background. But it will NOT range if the user has explicitly closed the app entirely. One interesting way to handle this might be to use Passbook: it's the only "app" that will wake up your phone from a 'closed' state is my understanding.

Comment: Understood, but this is a more specific use case than mentioned in the question.  If you run an app at least once to set up an iBeacon monitoring region, then reboot your phone (ensuring your app is not running in the background as the question asks), iOS will launch the app into the background on a region change.  This can be demonstrated by my example app in the blog post linked above, which is basically what the question asks for.

Comment: As of iOS 7.1, this has changed. I can kill the app from the app switcher, and an iBeacon will wake up the app, then I can successfully range it. This works even if I reboot the device.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to note that as of iOS 7.1+, even if the user explicitly force-kills the application, if it was monitoring for beacon regions at this point the application will be launched again and be able to run in the background for a short period of time.

Comment: Do you know how long is this "short period of time" ? And what you are allowed to do during this time ?

Comment: AFAIK that time is approx. 5 seconds.

Comment: Do you know if we can do "what we do" ? Like writting a file into log ?

Comment: I've done everything from send a quick server request, to range for any nearby beacons, log stuff, etc. As long as you know you've only got a short time and can finish what you're doing, I don't think there's any restriction on what you can do in that ~5 seconds..

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you read everything about background processing in iOS. From my understanding, it is as much a function of how much the user runs the app as well as system resources. The OS, from what I understand adapts to app usage and marshals all processes to support app usage. I doubt that this is cut and dried.

For content downloads, push messages are recommended - to kick off an update from time to time. I would not be surprised if push might have to push a message or two to "re-register" as it were.